# Google maps api issue with intellij

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, intellij-idea

I have followed the instructions on the android developers website on how to import the good maps api ( i have my key and i have installed google play services ) but I keep getting this error

`android-apt-compiler: [PosApp] C:\Users\\Desktop\examplesjss4e\PosApp\AndroidManifest.xml:8: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'value' with value '@integer/google_play_services_version').`

Any help would be great!!!

Comment: You have not referenced google play services library project

Comment: http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html. follow the link